# Creating a grid view to view contents of camera roll in a view

Tags: ios, uiview, camera, aqgridview

I am trying to create a custom way for the user to select items from their camera roll, a bit like instagram does in their app. When the user presses the select from camera roll button, I would like the grid with all of the images to slide up over the camera. I was thinking of using AQGridView to create the grid, but my problem is that because you need a view controller for the AQGridView, I can't make it appear in the overlay view controller. I need the grid to be in a UIView so that I can present it in the camera's custom overlay. How would I make it so that the grid is in a view, not a view controller.

Here is the kind of thing I am looking to create (from instagrams camera):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do I miss something or did you overlook iOS builtin UICOllectionView? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html